# How to save information as variables with html5

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm making a simple point and click stock simulator for school using html 5. I have a form set up, and they click submit to send the information. Is there a way to call that variable forward and to have it appear in it's current form. Math will be behind it. For instance, if they submit 3, it could fluctuate to different numbers, is there a way to display the fluctuation real time?

Comment: Yup. There is. Provide what you've tried. This site is for specific problems, not program building. I assume (PHP, Rails, Django, SQL) for your stored data?

Comment: for me, is not clear what you are asking, as @nicholas wrote I would expect you to specify your backend

Comment: @juanpastas I guess he is not yet familiar with the back end concept.

Answer (score 0):

The form inputs are posted to the web server and handled there. you need to familiarize yourself with that concept first.

Eg.

asp.net:

```
Request.QueryString["key"];
```

php

```
$_POST["key"];
```

Google these and see how you get on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out KnockoutJS.  Using data-bind on the HTML elements, you can construct a viewmodel in javascript that would hold these values, and update them in real time.

http://www.knockoutjs.com for knockout itself, and http://learn.knockoutjs.com for some really good tutorials (and if those don't work out for you, there's always SO).